# Is it possible to free up phone storage while keeping HTC Sense?

Tags: htc-sense, app2sd

I recently factory-reset my HTC Desire to free up space for apps, because it was suffering from constant 'low space' warnings, and it wasn't possible to free up space.

(Initially I installed Cyanogenmod, but didn't like various things about it, so returned to the HTC Sense UI).

However I can see the phone storage problem is going to come back soon - after moving 4 apps off the phone and onto SD card (the only 4 that supported this) I ended up with **10MB LESS space** on the phone!

So I am wondering if there's a way to get more stuff off the phone and onto the SD card while keeping the HTC Sense UI. I have heard of 'A2SD+' for example. Can I use that while retaining HTC Sense?

(My phone is rooted and has S-OFF).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have the safe device and had faced the same problem. I have two wonderful solutions:

1) Use [link2sd](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en). This app moves your app's apk, lib and dex file to second partition of you SD card. It will leave only the data files in the internal memory. So you can install nearly five times the more apps. I have a blog [post](http://techspalace.blogspot.com/2011/10/increase-free-space-on-htc-desire.html) if you want to try it out.

2) Use [sueprnova](http://supernova.droidzone.in/) ROM. This ROM is the stock ROM with data2sd support. So you can even use 2GB of SD space as internal memory.

Both of this solution requires you to have a better class of SD Card.

Comment: A better class of SD Card - meaning a faster SD card than the one that came with the phone?

Comment: Yes. Class 4 or class 6 SD card. As the files will reside on SD card the speed matters.

Comment: New card ordered!

Comment: I thought I would give an update: I installed suprnova on a 10x SD card (requirement was for a slower 6x card). I have been able to install as many apps as I want, but the downside is that the phone is incredibly slow to use. On balance I am not sure if I'd recommend going through the hassle to others.

Answer (score 1):

I have a LeeDroid Rom on my Desire, and it has Sense and A2SD+. There are many roms with sense...

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like the answer is to install a ROM with Sense (and presumably also do some work to set up A2SD+).

Comment: Yes. But it really requires very little works to set up A2SD+ with a rom that includes it. I only had to partition and format the SD card in a particular way before flashing the phone.